# Create a button made by an icon so that icon is fills it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview

How can I make a button that hasn’t any text but just an image as icon? I already tried using imageEdset setting the button this way:

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIImageEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
```

But the image appears not centered and stretched

Comment: Why are you setting edge insets? How do you want your image to look?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I want it to fill the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *fill* the button, then you should set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `.scaleAspectFill`.

```
button.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

**Warning**: This will only show the full image if the image aspect ratio and your imageView aspect ratio *match*.

If you want the *full image* to be displayed, then you should set the `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit`

```
button.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```